# SIM-Card Filesystem in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, filesystem

On my old Nokia Phone it was possible to store Data-Files on to the SIM-Card.
Does anybody how to access the SIM-Card's File system within Ubuntu Touch?

May I need to mount it first? But I can't identify the SIM-Card in /dev.

Comment: What do you mean `store Data-Files on to the SIM-Card` You could add a few numbers to the chip, but data files ? You mean like music of documents ? Are you sure your `old nokia` just did not have an undisclosed storage space ?

Comment: SIM cards shouldn't have any data space except for phone numbers/contacts. They would be the only thing that could be put on. Even if you somehow managed to put a tiny file on the card, there would be no way to access that with Ubuntu because there are no SIM adapters for computers, AFAIK. Are you sure you don't mean SD card?

Comment: Okay, I see, you are right. My old Nokia showed up two devices in the FileManager: Card(2GB) and PhoneStorage(About some MBs). I though the PhoneStorage is the SIM-Card itself. But it seems to be a little storage onto the phone. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zacharee1 is right. There is no filesystem on the SIM-Card.

My old Nokia showed up two devices in the FileManager: Card(2GB) and PhoneStorage(About some MBs). I though the PhoneStorage is the SIM-Card itself. But it seems to be a little storage onto the phone. :-(

Thanks for helping!